# Making dotted tables (like the default TOC)

Tags: tables

I want to set a table to look something like this:

```
        Ferguson...........................  135 pounds.
        Kennedy............................  153   ”
        Joe................................  120   ”
        Weight of the outside balloon......  650   ”
        Weight of the second balloon.......  510   ”
        Car and network....................  280   ”
        Anchors, instruments, awnings,
         and sundry utensils, guns,
         coverings, etc....................  190   ”
        Meat, pemmican, biscuits, tea,
         coffee, brandy....................  386   ”
        Water..............................  400   ”
        Apparatus..........................  700   ”
        Weight of the hydrogen.............  276   ”
        Ballast............................  200   ”
                                          -----
                                          4,000 pounds.
```

The table itself isn't difficult, but how can I get the lines of `.`'s? I don't want a ruled table, because it would look out of place in the text block of the novel, but I do need some way to visually connect small cells (e.g. `Joe` and `120`). I think the dots are the best way to do this, and I'm mainly looking for a way to set this specific solution, but I would also be curious to hear suggestions on other solutions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

I used `<{\dotfill}` in order to automatically add the dots in all rows of the table. With the help of `@{\;}` I slightly decreased the space between the dots and the following number. I also added `>{\hangindent=10pt}` in order to get the hanging indentation in entries that occupy multiple lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{\hangindent=10pt}b{5cm}<{\dotfill}@{\;}l}
some text here                              & 100 \\
text                                        & 200 \\
a longer text that occupies multiple lines  & 300 \\
text                                        & 400\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another variant with three columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, booktabs} 

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ >{\raggedright}b{5cm} <{\,\dotfill}@{\enspace}l@{\:}c}
Ferguson & 135 & pounds. \\
        Kennedy & 153 & ” \\
        Joe & 120 & ”\\
        Weight of the outside balloon & 650 & ”\\
        Weight of the second balloon & 510 & ”\\
        Car and network & 280 & ” \\
        Anchors, instruments, awnings,
         and sundry utensils, guns,
         coverings, etc. & 190 & ”\\
        Meat, pemmican, biscuits, tea,
         coffee, brandy & 386 & ”\\
        Water & 400 & ”\\
        Apparatus & 700 & ”\\
        Weight of the hydrogen & 276 & ”\\
        Ballast. & 200 & ”\\
\cmidrule(r{-0.8em}){2-2}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{2}{@{\,}l}{ 4,000 pounds.}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]